# Error while using vagrant to deploy ruby/rbenv using railsbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, ansible

I used railbox to create a [configuration](https://railsbox.io) that I can deploy through vagrant.
However, the setup is stopped by the following error.

```
==> myapp: fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'ansible.vars.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'git'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/ansible/roles/ruby/tasks/rbenv.yml': line 15, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Install plugins\n  ^ here\n"}
```

The content of rbenv.yml:

```
---
- name: Install libffi-dev
  apt: name=libffi-dev

- name: Clone rbenv repository to ~/.rbenv
  git: repo={{ rbenv_repo }} dest={{ rbenv_path }} version={{ rbenv_version }} accept_hostkey=yes
  sudo_user: '{{ user_name }}'

- name: Create rbenv.sh
  template: src=rbenv.sh.j2 dest={{ profile_d_path }}/rbenv.sh owner={{ user_name }} group={{ group_name }}

- name: Create plugins directory
  file: path={{ rbenv_plugins_path }} state=directory owner={{ user_name }} group={{ group_name }}

- name: Install plugins
  git: repo={{ item.git }} dest={{ rbenv_plugins_path }}/{{ item.name }} version={{ item.version }} accept_hostkey=yes
  sudo_user: '{{ user_name }}'
  with_items: rbenv_plugins

- name: Check if ruby installed
  shell: '{{ rbenv_bin }} versions | grep -q {{ rbenv_ruby_version }}'
  register: ruby_installed
  ignore_errors: yes
  sudo_user: '{{ user_name }}'

- name: Install ruby
  command: '{{ rbenv_bin }} install {{ rbenv_ruby_version }}'
  sudo_user: '{{ user_name }}'
  when: ruby_installed|failed

- name: Set global ruby version
  command: '{{ rbenv_bin }} global {{ rbenv_ruby_version }}'
  sudo_user: '{{ user_name }}'

- name: Rehash rbenv
  command: '{{ rbenv_bin }} rehash'
  sudo_user: '{{ user_name }}'
```

What is wrong with the yml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run a recent version of Ansible (I believe it was changed for 2.2) you need to write with jinja2 syntax

```
- name: Install plugins
  git: repo={{ item.git }} dest={{ rbenv_plugins_path }}/{{ item.name }} version={{ item.version }} accept_hostkey=yes
  sudo_user: '{{ user_name }}'
  with_items: '{{ rbenv_plugins }}'
```